# CentOS 6.5 blank screen after an update

Tags: filesystems, centos

I just updated my CentOS 6.5 with the following command:

```
sudo yum update
```

after the update it asked for a restart and I did it but than now when the loading bar finishes loading I have a totally blank screen and nothing shows. I tried hitting Alt + F1 to access the console but it doesn't work either. Even Ctrl + Alt + del does not restart the server. I have to hard hit the reset button on the server to make it restart. All I am able to access is the GRUB tool when I have the grub option list to load the O.S and than I can hit "c" and have access to Grub console.

I have a second disk in this server where I have ubuntu installed so I am still able to load Ubuntu. 
From ubuntu I am able to run parted command so "parted -l" shows all available disks, CentoOS is installed in the first one from the list(ATA KINGSTON) I am lost here and not able to recover from this, any help will be very much appreciated:

```
mmaia@mmaia-desktop-ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA KINGSTON SV300S3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 120GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  525MB  524MB  primary  ext4         boot
 2      525MB   120GB  120GB  primary               lvm


Model: ATA SAMSUNG HD103SI (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  1000GB  1000GB  primary  ext4         boot


Model: ATA OCZ-VERTEX4 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  105GB  105GB   primary   ntfs            boot
 2      105GB   250GB  145GB   primary   ext4
 3      250GB   256GB  6200MB  extended
 5      250GB   256GB  6200MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)


Model: ATA ST31000524AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  primary  ntfs         boot
```

Update:
Whenever I try to mount my CentOS disk from Ubuntu with command:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda /media/centos -t ext4
```

I get an error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

Comment: try mount /dev/sda1 or mount /dev/sda2 depending what you want to mount.
basically check the root partition and then /media/centos/var/log/X
for anything unusual, dmesg file, messages, syslog.
additional check the installation logs. you most likely will find an error there somewhere.

Comment: I tryied mounting dev/sda2 and got the following message: mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'

Comment: sorry didn't see the lvm flag.
basically you have to execute the "lvm" mount commands then.
google will help :)